# form_for method using slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have looked at the documentation of slim, and I still can't figure out how to do this in slim:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I try to translate the first line like this

```
= form_for([@post, @post.reviews.build]) do |f|
```

But I am getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Was experiencing a similar issue earlier, I think you just need some child elements! Try this:

```
= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f|
  div.field
    = f.label :commenter
    br
    = f.text_field :commenter
  div.field
    = f.label :body
    br
    = f.text_area :body
  div.actions
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Mario wrote:

> = form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f|
>         div.field
>           = f.label :commenter
>           br
>           = f.text_field :commenter
>         div.field
>           = f.label :body
>           br
>           = f.text_area :body
>         div.actions
>           = f.submit

Div is not necessary . So I would do :

```
= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :commenter
    br
    = f.text_field :commenter
  .field
    = f.label :body
    br
    = f.text_area :body
  .actions
    = f.submit
```